# AppleScript to click for difficult webpage like Google Finance

Tags: javascript, html, applescript

Here is the webpage I want to click.

( https://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSE%3AMA&fstype=ii&ei=lwwmU_CqK6G3iALIHw )

And, there, I want to click "Balance Sheet" or "Cash Flow" using AppleScript.

Here is the AppleScript I'm trying:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('t')[3].click();" in front document
end tell
```

It looks there is no error in the webpage when I try the AppleScript, but the tag() doesn't have "href", it may not work as I expected. I guess the page uses external javascript(?) by the event from the real click (using mouse or trackpad), but I don't know how I can do via AppleScript. I'm new AppleScript and Javascript/HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case your mouse can be occupied for a brief moment, you can write an automatic mouse movement and clicking with [MouseTools](http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/MouseTools/MouseTools.html). Download "the compiled command line tool", unzip and move the MouseTools executable file on your desktop. Then try running this code in AppleScript Editor:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    open location "https://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSE%3AMA&fstype=ii&ei=lwwmU_CqK6G3iALIHw"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Safari"
    tell window 1
        set {size, position} to {{600, 600}, {0, 22}}
    end tell
end tell

delay 2 --wait for the page to load, increase if too low.

set mouseToolsPath to (path to home folder as text) & "Desktop:MouseTools"
set x to 350
set y to 235
do shell script quoted form of POSIX path of mouseToolsPath & " -x " & (x as text) & " -y " & (y as text) & " -mouseSteps 1"
do shell script quoted form of POSIX path of mouseToolsPath & " -leftClickNoRelease"
do shell script quoted form of POSIX path of mouseToolsPath & " -releaseMouse"
```

Comment: Thank you. It works when the applescript editor is running and let it run (command-R). However, it does not work when the applescript editor is not running and let it run over top panel applescript icon. That is, store your script into ~/Library/Scripts/ and run it over top panel icon.

Comment: Found what was wrong when it runs over the icon. Looks like resizing window has an issue. But I know how to maximize a window, so replacing of it, everything works fine. Thank you!